# How to get different row counts of two different tables in one query with help of group by clause

Tags: mysql, database, oracle11g, database-administration

I have one Parent table(Order) and one child table(Item). One user can order multiple orders in one day and one order may have multiple Item.

My table structure like,

[image: Order Table]
[image: Item table]

I would like to get result like, in one how many orders and Items have ordered by particular user.

I need result like

[image: Result]

Thank you.

Comment: Image not opening.. Cant help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you just mention column names in text for used tables so that we can help.

Comment: please decide about the database system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try to use `distinct count` for the `count columns`, and `grouping by user_id` is enough as :*

```
select o.user_id as "User Id",
       count(distinct o.id_order) as "Count(Order)",
       count(distinct i.id_item) as "Count(Item)",
       max("date") as "Date"
  from orders o
  join item i on o.id_order = i.id_order
 group by user_id;

User Id Count(Order)  Count(Item)    Date
------- ------------  -----------  ----------
   1         3            7        22.11.2018
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/KNE81778)

Comment: Thanks!!. this works for me. Only I need a data date wise also. So i have removed max(date) and keep it in group by clause.

Comment: @swapnil you're welcome friend. Don't forget to mark the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **INNER JOIN** for user,order and item table. also use **GROUP BY** clause for group each date and order.

```
SELECT user_id,
       count(o.id_order),
       count(item.id_item)
FROM USER
INNER JOIN
`ORDER` o ON user.id=o.id_order
INNER JOIN item i ON o.id_order=o.id_order
GROUP BY o.Date, o.id_order
```